# Ports coming up as closed after port forwarding

Tags: port, forwarding

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPhMT.png)
I was helping my friend attempt to port forward his Minecraft server but it turns out that his port forwarding gateway is a lot different than mine. He uses Huawei. I'm not sure what we did wrong but whenever we launch the server and check the port it comes up as closed. Hopefully somebody more experienced can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post the content of the image into your question? It's kind of unclear what you're asking! Thanks :)

Comment: I thought the image was embedded, sorry. I am using mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave the "external source port number" empty. This is only used to restrict incoming traffic to only those ports.

Are there any other routers between the server and the modem? In which 'mode' is the Huawei? Since this is a modem/router combo. If used in bridge, port forwarding doesn't work.

Comment: They have 2 routers but he has an Ethernet cable going into the modem. Please define mode as me or him don't have much experience with stuff like this.

Comment: Look under WAN, then there should be at least one connection. Pick the one that says internet. If you have telephone there could also be a VOIP connection (leave that one alone). Then, check what it says near 'WAN mode'. 'Bride WAN' means that your modem doesn't have router functionality like port forwarding. If it says something like Routed WAN you are good to go. Warning: If you change this from bridge wan to routed wan, you have a possibility that other devices on the network stop working (then it probably was put on bridged for a reason).